# what should i clean if i use Interface Builder for creating views

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, interface-builder

When Interface Builder has created subview (any UIView) for me then do i need to remove it from superview and release it myself in dealloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not unless you have a separate outlet for it that you're managing yourself. `UIViews` that exist solely as subviews in IB are managed by the state of their superview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting you IBOutlets in Interface Builder and have created @properties in your controller to retain them then you will need to release them yourself, since your controller will have increased the retain count on the object.